# Roasting rack? I'm stumped as to what this is....Help! :)

Tags: equipment, cookware, roasting, kitchen

[image]A friend gave me a bunch of her old inherited cooking accoutrement and I'm not entirely sure what the function of this is.  Anyone know?[image]

Comment: Guesswork here, but the left one has the shape of many deep fryer and would seem like a it might be to get items separated while frying, but it also has a similar shape to some rib racks used in smokers and grills.  The right item looks very similar to racks used to fry taco shells.

Comment: I'm having a little difficulty picturing the left one in three dimensions.  Could you also post a view from the end, and maybe at an oblique angle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rack on the left appears to be the "King Kooker 12-Slot Leg and Wing Rack for Poultry". It is used for roasting or grilling chicken drumsticks or whole wings.

Comment: [Photo](http://assets.academy.com/mgen/90/10336390.jpg) of its use.

Answer (score 7):

The rack on the right looks just like a rack to hold tacos. See the below image:
[image: taco rack]

Comment: Not necessarily 'finished'.  You drop the hard shells in there, and then you can add whatever fillings w/out worrying about them falling over.

Comment: @kayk  I was comparing to ones for dropping into a fryer, often that would be with the two of them pressed together, but you are likely correct, more of an assembly rack rather than for frying the shell.  The left might be more for carrying, though the mix of rounded and squared off peaks and troughs is throwing me.

Comment: On second thought, (I know it's been almost 2 months :) ) the rack could be used to turn tortilla wraps into taco shells. See this link. http://www.momables.com/how-to-make-hard-crunchy-taco-shells/ I doubt that's what it's meant for though